# String value within a string value

Tags: string, lua

As stated above is the thing I am attempting to accomplish. I am using Pilot.Lua

```
local a = "I am a text"
local textbox = ({value="local a = "I am a text""})
```

Problem here is that if I was to transfer this sample code into "textbox" I would receive an error due to the "I am a text" being read as code rather than a string value. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes

```
local textbox = ({value='local a = "I am a text"'})
```

or long strings:

```
local textbox = ({value=[[local a = "I am a text"]]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotation marks with backslashes

```
local a = "I am a text"
local textbox = ({value="local a = \"I am a text\""})
```